# Why compiler doesn't complain the wrong enum value

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>

enum IsOptionAEnum
{
    IsOptionA_YES,
    IsOptionA_NO
};

enum IsOptionBEnum
{
    IsOptionB_YES,
    IsOptionB_NO
};

void TestFunc(IsOptionAEnum optionA, IsOptionBEnum optionB)
{
    if (optionA == IsOptionA_YES || optionA == IsOptionB_YES) // typo
    {
        // ...
    }

    //if (optionA == IsOptionA_YES || optionB == IsOptionB_YES) // correct one
    //{
    //}

}
```

Question> `optionA` is of type `IsOptionAEnum` and doesn't have the value of `IsOptionB_YES`. Why does the compiler of VS2010 not find this error?

If it is the case where compiler cannot find the error, is there a way that I can enforce this restriction so that compiler can find the error?

Comment: You can use `enum class`es instead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whilst the standard doesn't render this an error (enums are effectively syntax over integers), this is certainly something a compiler can detect. [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org), compiling with `-Wenum-compare`, gives:

```
Bonsai:~ adamw$ clang++ test.cpp 
    test.cpp:15:45: warning: comparison of two values with different enumeration
      types ('IsOptionAEnum' and 'IsOptionBEnum') [-Wenum-compare]
    if (optionA == IsOptionA_YES || optionA == IsOptionB_YES) // typo
                                    ~~~~~~~ ^  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

It may be that Visual C++ doesn't warn about this by default. Try setting the `/Wall` flag on the compiler, which will enable all warnings. If it still doesn't warn, you can file a request with the VC compiler team.

Edit: As other answers and comments have mentioned, if you have a VC11, you can use [Strongly typed enums](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2347.pdf).

Answer (score 5):

Pre-C++11, enum types do not provide the type-safety you are looking for, and are essentially pretty integers.

You want the strongly typed enum class:
http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-nullptr-strongly-typed-enum-class.html

Answer (score 1):

The non-C++11 solution is to use `struct`s

```
struct IsOptionAEnum
{
    int val;
    static IsOptionAEnum IsOptionA_YES;
    static IsOptionAEnum IsOptionA_NO;

    IsOptionAEnum( int v ): val(v) {}
};

IsOptionAEnum::IsOptionA_YES(0);
IsOptionAEnum::IsOptionA_YES(1);

if( optionA == IsOptionAEnum::IsOptionA_YES ) // this is type-safe
    // etc.
```

It's possible to drop the internal value if you don't need it (you need to disable copying, always pass by reference and compare the addresses of the structs).

In C++11 you can use [typed enums](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-nullptr-strongly-typed-enum-class.html) as Prashant has suggested.